# Image component not working on android in react native for android using expo in react-native-image?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

react-native-image: how to resolve the issue of image component not working on android in react native for android using expo? I'm trying with below code:

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: require("../../assets/images/TLC_Icon.png")
  }}
  style={{
    minHeight: 100,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    margin: 5
  }}
/>
```

This code works well on the website but somehow it doesn't  work on my android phone.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using local file as source of image, not the internet image, so you don't need uri.

0

```
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/TLC_Icon.png")}
        style={{
          minHeight: 100,
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          margin: 5
        }}
      />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what confused me is that it is working great on the web. let me remove the uri. :)